# Find server ip address on local network

Tags: java, server, client, client-server, serversocket

I wrote a simple server-client software that runs on a local network /24 (255.255.255.0)and I don't know how to find the ip address when it changes.

- The ip address of the server is not static.
- I can't save the mac address and then retrieve the ip address from the arp table because it will run on different machines.

The only way for clients to find the correct ip address is to try the whole range until the connection gets accepted?

Comment: if your client and server are in the same local network, then you can make you server listening on all local IP address simply by using 0.0.0.0. 
Otherwise, you have to buy a dedicated IP address or buy a hosting server in order to deploy your application server. This way, your server will be reachable with https: //hostname/you-application-server

Comment: This is why we have "names".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) of the server instead of the IP. When IP changes the hostname should stay the same.

You can establish the hostname in many ways. Either programmatically:

```
 String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

Or with an OS command or a tool.

For example, on Windows it could be

```
ipconfig /all
```

On Linux it could probably be

```
hostname
```

or

```
hostnamectl
```

Once you know the hostname you could use it to establish a connection. Alternatively, you could also get the IP of the server programmatically on any client in the local network. In Java you could use the following code:

```
InetAddress.getByName("serverHostName").getHostAddress()
```

Comment: I am confused. I should get the hostName on the Server and the hostAddress on the Client every time before connecting in order to find the IP address of the server?
How would the client know which is the hostname? Please note that the server can be hosted every time on a different machine.

Comment: How do you know how to get to stackoverflow.com?  The answer is that you know the name, and then you use the name  in a connect request (in your case, type it into a web browser). You have to start with some knowledge.  If you don't know the name of the machine and you don't know the address of the machine, either (a) you're stuck, or (b) you have to invent some way of finding something out.